# Difficulty in writing a mathematical solution

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I find it really difficult to write a mathematical solution for a probability problem. Let me take an example:

> A counting process $(N_t)_{t\ge 0}$ has the independent increment property if, for every $k>0$, and every $k$-tuple of times $0<t_1<t_2<\cdots <t_k$, the $k$-tuple of random variables $N_{t_1}, (N_{t_2}-N_{t_1}),\ldots, (N_{t_{k}}-N_{t_{k-1}})$ are independent.
>
> Prove that the Poisson process has the independent increment property.

In Poisson process, $N_t$ is the number of occurences (or arrivals) in $(0,t]$. My thought goes like this: take arbitrary two random variables of those, for example, $N_{t_2}-N_{t_1}$ and $N_{t_4}-N_{t_3}$. For every $i$, $N_{t_i}-N_{t_{i-1}}$ indicates the number of occurences in $(t_{i-1},t_i]$. Then, by the memoryless property of Poisson process, number of occurences in $(t_1,t_2]$ tells nothing about the number of occurences in $(t_3,t_4]$, so $N_{t_2}-N_{t_1}$ and $N_{t_4}-N_{t_3}$ are independent.

Is my thought correct, and how can we write an "official" proof for the above statement?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Hint: Start from the *mathematical definition* of a Poisson process. What is it, already?

Comment: There are so many equivalent definitions for a Poisson process, but let me take the definition in the article which I am reading: A Poisson process is a renewal process in which the interarrival intervals have an exponential distribution function.

Comment: Thus you are ready to compute $$P(N_{t_1}=n_1, N_{t_2}-N_{t_1}=n_2,\ldots, N_{t_{k}}-N_{t_{k-1}}=n_k)$$ for every $(n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_k)$.